# Is there a OPENSSL patch for WSO2 ESB 4.6.0?

Tags: wso2-esb

Does the OPENSSL patch for WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 exist in the WSO2 web site or do we have to download it from the openssl site and then build the ESB from source code ? Got any instructions for building the ESB with patch files ?

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL is an open-source implementation of the SSL and TLS protocols. It is widely used in unix-based OSes. It does nothing to WSO2 esb. Wso2 esb is standalone application you can download it and use it easily.